Invoking dbt macro directly from the DAG file in Airflow
I am trying to invoke a macro directly from the DAG file as a task rather than being invoked from any of the model. Below is the code, I am using which is not working as expected, please help on this,
run_macro = DbtTaskGroup(
    group_id="dbt_run_macro",
    project_config=ProjectConfig(
        dbt_project_path="/usr/local/airflow/dags/dbt/project_folder"
    ),
    profile_config=profile_config,
    execution_config=execution_config,
    operator_args={"select": "run-operation"},
    render_config=RenderConfig(
        select=["path:macros"]
    ),
)

The code does not rendering any of the macros, but without render_config, it selects all the models and snapshots. So, the problem is that, its not picking up any macros from macros folder, which holds upto 7-8 macros in it.
Use case/motivation
The code should pick up the all or specific macro and execute it successfully from the DAG file, rather than invoking from any of the models. All the macros runs perfectly outside of airflow using the command dbt run-operation macro_name

Do you have the macro-paths: ["macros"] configured in your dbt_project.yml?

@OluwafemiSule yes macro-paths is already in place
